# Upgrade Symfony 3.0 to 3.2 -> Call to a member function getRepository() on null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I just upgraded my Symfony app from 3.0 to 3.2.

To do so, I simply created a new Symfony 3.2 project and copied and pasted all my work from the old project to the new one. Which means, some folders like controller, services, routing, and so on...

Everything seems to be working fine except when I'm calling a page that's using doctrine. It is always returning me the following exception :
"Error: Call to a member function getRepository() on null"

Here is how I call my repo :

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->findAll();
```

Is there anything that has change in the syntax in 3.2 ? I can't find anything about that on internet.

Comment: It should be: `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')->findAll();`

Also why didn't you update your project with composer? After of course resolving the deprecations, which are listed on the upgrade guide: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.1.md and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.2.md

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I accidently put a 'em' between getManager and getRepo, but it isn't there in my code. It's a typo, sorry.. I didn't do it that way because I thought it was quicker to do it like I did, since my project is not that big